# Can't maximize width of button inside listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class OnBoardingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: _getConstraints(context),
          child: Padding(
            padding: _getPadding(context),
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior:
                  ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
              child: ListView(
                children: [const AwardsSection()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AwardsSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const AwardsSection({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: awards
              .map((award) => Card(
                    elevation: 3,
                    surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 8, vertical: 16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(award.imageUrl),
                          const SizedBox(height: 16),
                          ResponsiveText(
                              text: award.title,
                              textStyle: getResponsiveTextStyle(
                                  context, AppTextTheme.title)),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 32,
                          ),
                          OutlinedButton(
                              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                  minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(48)),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Text("Hello")) // <---- This I want full width in each card
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
final List<AwardModel> awards = [
  AwardModel(imageUrl: 'images/award_1.png', title: "Stage 1 & 2 Winners"),
  AwardModel(
      imageUrl: "images/award_2.png", title: "Second place in 3/4 events"),
  AwardModel(
      imageUrl: "images/award_3.png", title: "Finalist in the virtual circuit")
];
```

```
class AwardModel {
  String imageUrl;
  String title;

  AwardModel({required this.imageUrl, required this.title});
}
```

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
The offending constraints were:
BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 40.0<=h<=Infinity)
The relevant error-causing widget was:
OutlinedButton
OutlinedButton:file:///C:/Users/krisarya/My%20Profile/Github-krishnaacharya-official/flutter-landing-page/app/lib/onboarding/presentation/widgets/award_section.dart:40:27
award_section.dart:40
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw*
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 519:9                                 throwError
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 569:11                                
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 576:14                                debugAssertIsValid
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2386:23                            layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2382:11                               layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 279:7                           performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2493:7                             layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2382:11                               layout
he following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderConstrainedBox#f151b relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
creator: ConstrainedBox ← _InputPadding ← Semantics ← OutlinedButton ← Column ← Padding ← Semantics
← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#ddc19 ink renderer] ←
NotificationListener ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
size: MISSING
additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 40.0<=h<=Infinity)
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
child: RenderPhysicalShape#51eaf NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: RenderCustomPaint#a155c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: _RenderInkFeatures#7a4e5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#1ca50 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
child: RenderMouseRegion#7191b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your outlined button widget with expanded, it should solve the problem like this

```
Expanded(
child: OutlinedButton(
 style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
 minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(48)),
 onPressed: () {},
 child: const Text("Hello")
))
```

Comment: You are crazy, you are suggesting me to use expanded inside listview. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: No I am saying to use it in the cards.